# neo4j There is no procedure with the name `algo.pageRank` registered for this database instance

Tags: neo4j

```
:param label => ('Person');
:param relationshipType => ('HAS_EMAILED');
:param limit => ( 100);
:param config => ({concurrency: 8, direction: 'Outgoing', weightProperty: null, defaultValue: 1, dampingFactor: 0.85, iterations: 25, writeProperty: 'pagerank'});

//then we calculate pagerank with one simple command
CALL algo.pageRank($label, $relationshipType, $config);
```

*****There is an error that happened here:**

Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound: There is no procedure with the name `algo.pageRank` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

I use the "Graph Data Science Library" plugin in Neo4j

Comment: Can you verify the installation for `algo` using `CALL algo.list()`? What version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: I have fixed the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65067779/call-gds-pagerank-stream-problems