# CALL gds.pagerank.stream problems

Tags: neo4j

> :param label => ('Person');  :param relationshipType =>
> ('HAS_EMAILED');  :param limit => ( 100); :param config =>
> ({concurrency: 8, direction: 'Outgoing', weightProperty: null,
> defaultValue: 1, dampingFactor: 0.85, iterations: 25, writeProperty:
> 'pagerank'});    //then we calculate pagerank with one simple command
> CALL  algo.pageRank($label, $relationshipType, $config);

How turn this into a `CALL gds.pagerank.stream(...)`?

[I saw his on the Bruggen Blog][1]
[1]: https://blog.bruggen.com/2019/12/part-23-revisiting-hillary-clintons.html

Answer (score 0):

My solutions:

```
:param label => ('Person'); :param relationshipType => ('HAS_EMAILED'); :param limit => ( 100); :param config => ({concurrency: 8, direction: 'Outgoing', weightProperty: null, defaultValue: 1, dampingFactor: 0.85, iterations: 25, writeProperty: 'pagerank'});

CALL gds.graph.create(
    'myGraph332',
    'Person',    { HAS_EMAILED:{orientation:'UNDIRECTED'}    })
```

Then

```
CALL gds.pageRank.stream('myGraph332')

YIELD nodeId, score

RETURN gds.util.asNode(nodeId).alias AS alias, score

ORDER BY score DESC, alias ASC
```